# Imbalance between North and South hemisphere jet streams

Tags: jet-stream

I've been tracking the global jet streams for several years now. Over time, I've noticed that the Northern hemisphere jet streams appear much thinner, slower, and less well organized than their counterparts to the South, which appear much more robust and better organized. What's going on here, and does this imbalance have any significance/meaning with respect to climate change?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe it has something to do with the imbalance between North and South hemisphere landmasses?

Comment: @AndreVirly Hardly unexpected. It depends on the season as well. There is greater land mass in the NH and jet stream is influenced by climate change and emissions. The greater amount of land mass forces Rossby waves and hence there are splits and joins.